# ClickableSpan AND onClickListener on TextView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, onclick, touch-event

I need to have both on a TextView:
When the TextView is clicked, trigger a function. But when a certain part of the text is clicked, trigger a different function.

So I have a ClickableSpan for that certain part, and an OnTouchListener on the whole TextView:

```
SpannableString string = new SpannableString(input);
// ...
string.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        functionOne();
    }
}, start, i, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(string);

// ...

textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Both work fine for themselves:

If I do not add the OnTouchListener, it calls `functionOne()`, triggered from the ClickableSpan.

But if I also add the OnTouchListener, it only calls `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)`. Also if I click on the certain part of the text, where the ClickableSpan should be triggered.

---

How can I have both?

So that if the certain part is clicked, the ClickableSpan is triggered, and if a different part of the text is clicked, then `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below function to achieve clickable span and there is no need to call touch listener. click event will be handled by ClickableSpan.

```
 fun setClickableSpan(
    spannable: Spannable,
    paths: ArrayList<String>,
    listener: EventListener
) {
    for (i in paths.indices) {
        val indexOfPath = spannable.toString().indexOf(paths[i])
        if (indexOfPath == -1) {
            continue
        }
        val clickableSpan: ClickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(textView: View) {
                listener.onItemClick(textView, i, paths[i])
            }
        }
        spannable.setSpan(
            clickableSpan, indexOfPath,
            indexOfPath + paths[i].length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )

    }
}
```